# How to kill php connection from client side?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am using jquery with php.

On  the client side the user can close the dialogbox or it will stop ajax request due to the time-out limit.

The problem is the mysql is still continue the process which is in the "sending data state".
But the php process no longer available because of:

```
set_time_limit(20);
```

Are there way to kill the PHP::PDO connection with  mysql process?

Thanks Arman.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was...

Comment: I don't know any php function / class, method to do this for you but if your mysql server is on the same host I guess you could just use the commandline to do this for you. You can make php execute commandline using the backticks `` or take a look at http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, how do you think you'd kill PHP <> MySQL connection from command line? By killing MySQL process or? How would that even be usable for more than 1 user?

Comment: @michael: mysql's `kill` command can kill queries and processes (e.g. logins/connnections).

Comment: Ok Marc, using PHP's `exec()` and MySQL's `kill`, how would you kill that one process that still in the "sending data state"? Reason I asked the question was to outline how the suggestion I read makes no sense at all. However, if you could show me how you'd make it work - I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're using persistent database connections. With those, the connection from mysql<->php is kept alive regardless of whether a client is actually connected or not. This allows queries to keep running and keeps any variables, locks, temporary tables, etc... to stay alive and gum up the works.

Disable persistent connections, and your 'stuck' queries will die when the client disconnects and PHP cleans up afterwards.

Comment: thanks for pointing but PDO by default has dbh->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT)= false;